# Connecting to gmail pop server by Windows command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, telnet, gmail-pop

I'm using command line on Windows 7 or Windows Command Processor. I'm trying to connect to gmail pop server (pop.gmail.com) on port 995 because that is what I have seen on other Web sites. I want at least to get an "+OK Hello there" message. This is the command I wrote:

```
telnet pop.gmail.com 995
```

I'm not getting any answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you received?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port 995 is for SSL connection. You cannot do it with telnet. 
You could probably try OpenSSL and to test it that way.

```
openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995 -quiet
```

More info on OpenSSL for Windows is here:
[OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)

**ADDED:**

I have just tested with openssl command I gave you above. It works like a charm:

```
user@localhost$ openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995 -quiet
depth=1 /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
+OK Gpop ready for requests from 11.11.111.11 v45pf1517914yhk.21
```

Comment: I've tried too with 110, and it didnt work either. Do you know which port should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure of gmail's POP3 ports. I know I've used IMAP before and it worked just fine. I have just confirmed gmail.com does require TLS/SSL for POP3